# Check if any keys in a dictionary match any values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Let d(n) be defined as the sum of proper divisors of n (numbers less than n which divide evenly into n).
>   If d(a) = b and d(b) = a, where a ≠ b, then a and b are an amicable pair and each of a and b are called amicable numbers.
>
> For example, the proper divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110; therefore d(220) = 284. The proper divisors of 284 are 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142; so d(284) = 220.
>
> Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under 10000.

I came up with a dictionary that holds x:d(x) for all numbers 0 to 9999 like so:

```
sums = {x:sum(alecproduct.find_factors(x))-x for x,y in enumerate(range(10**4))}
```

Where alecproduct.findfactors is a function from my own module that returns a list of all the factors of a number

I'm not sure where to go from here, though. I've tried iterating over the dictionary and creating tuples out of each k-v pair like so:

```
for k,v in sums.items():
    dict_tups.append((k,v))
```

But I don't think this helps me. Any advice on how I can detect if any of the dictionary keys match any of the dictionary values?

Edit - My solution based on 6502's answer:

```
sums,ap = {x:sum(find_factors(x))-x for x,y in enumerate(range(10**4))}, []

for x in sums:
    y = sums[x]
    if sums.get(y) == x and x != y:
        ap.append(x)

print(ap)
print('\nSum: ', sum(ap))
```

Comment: I think you can simplify `sums = {x: sum(alecproduct.find_factors(x)) - x for x in range(10 ** 4)}`.

Comment: @Elias Strehle How so? I can't think of a faster way to do a dict comprehension

Comment: My comment contains the proposed simplification. I think you do not need the `enumerate`. Not too sure about Python 2 though...

Comment: I didn't even realize that you had changed the code, lol. I added enumerate because I was getting the `can't unpack int` error. I see that you removed the y and the enumerate, how does it know to put sum() in the value position without the y?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. The `:` separates key and value in a dict comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is almost solved already... just get all couples out:

```
for x in my_dict:
    y = my_dict[x]
    if my_dict.get(y) == x:
        # x/y is an amicable pair
        ...
```

note that every pair will be extracted twice (both `x`/`y` and `y`/`x`) and perfect numbers (numbers that are the sum of their divisors) only once; not sure from your problem text if 6/6 is considered an amicable pair or not.

Comment: This works perfectly. Just needed to add x != y to that if statement

Answer (score 0):

This code should give you a list of all keys that are also values.

```
my_test = [key for key in my_dict.keys() if key in my_dict.values()]
```

You don't need .keys() because, this is the default behavior however, I wanted to be explicit for this example.

Alternatively, a for loop example can be seen below.

```
for key, value in my_dict.iteritems():
    if key == value:
        print key # or do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sets:

```
x_dx = {(x, sum(alecproduct.find_factors(x)) - x) for x in range(10 ** 4)}
x_dx = {t for t in x_dx if t[0] != t[1]}
dx_x = {(t[1], t[0]) for t in x_dx}

amicable_pairs = x_dx & dx_x
```

As in 6502's answer, all amicable pairs are extracted twice.
A way to remove these 'duplicates' could be (although it's certainly a mouthful):

```
amicable_pairs_sorted = {tuple(sorted(t)) for t in amicable_pairs}
amicable_pairs_ascending = sorted(list(amicable_pairs_sorted))
```

Answer (score 0):

iterating through keys and values of your `sums` dictionary to create a new list with all the **`amicable numbers`** solves the problem, here is the code snippet.

```
amicable_list=[]
for i in sums.keys():
    if i in sums.values():
        if (sums.get(sums.get(i,-1),-1) == i) and (i != sums[i]):
            amicable_list.append(i)
```